# pygal ValueError: Invalid PI name 'b'xml''

Tags: python, pygal

relative code :hist.render_to_file('1.svg')

this picture show the details

[image]

I have try to install new version of lxml,but can't work;

The process I install it just like this:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
pip install lxml
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve it?

Thank you!

And later I have try to solve it as the conmment said,this is the result.

### How can I upgrade it?I failed to upgrade it...

```
davenny@davenny-X555LF:~$ pip install --upgrade pygal
Collecting pygal
  Downloading pygal-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 38kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pygal
  Found existing installation: pygal 1.7.0
    Uninstalling pygal-1.7.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pygal-1.7.0
  Rolling back uninstall of pygal
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pygal-2.4.0.dist-info'
davenny@davenny-X555LF:~$ pip list --outdated
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.


matplotlib (1.5.2rc2) - Latest: 2.0.2 [wheel]
pygal (1.7.0) - Latest: 2.4.0 [wheel]
python-dateutil (2.4.2) - Latest: 2.6.1 [wheel]
```

---

Comment: https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/282

Comment: Try running `pip install --upgrade pygal`. If it doesn't help use `pip list --outdated` or `pip list` to check the installed versions (pygal version should be at least 2.0.11). Edit your post and include the output as text (use Ctrl+Shift+C to copy from the terminal).

Comment: @tom I have edited it again ,could you help me ?

Comment: @tom I have solved it!Thank you very much!  And I solved it by this way:
pip install --user pygal==2.4