# ValueError: Invalid PI name 'xml' when running spcchart

Tags: python, xml, spc

I'm trying to run spcchart on Python 2.7 environment and turn out an error "ValueError: Invalid PI name 'xml'".
Error message attached and if anyone can tell where went wrong and how to fix it, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please *[copy-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/295370/how-to-copy-text-in-the-windows-command-line-cmd)* the error message into the question

Comment: A screen shot is nice but not *sufficient*.

Comment: https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/282

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45520049/pygal-valueerror-invalid-pi-name-bxml

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/Kozea/pygal/issues/282) in the package "pygal". The bug has been fixed, so upgrading to the latest version should fix the problem:

```
pip list --outdated
pip install pygal --upgrade
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44412503/))

Check that the first command lists pygal to confirm that it is installed and out of date. Then use the second command to upgrade it.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for support and it seems the error fixed although some other issue with this spcchart program.